# IE9 running in compatible mode (IE7 standard) does not run jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am having weird problem with IE9 in compatible mode(IE 7 standard) running Jquery(1.8.1)
sometimes it runs the jQuery command  other times it just does not take any action on the button when its clicked. The code is below for this simple page. I am using tiles to include resources like javascript , css.

When I click on the button sometimes it runs the logic other times it does not, I debugged using f12 I can see page has downloaded jQuery js for this to run. Please let me know what I have missed for this weird behavior.

```
<div style="margin: 50px 20px 50px 20px; text-align: center;">

<span>Do you want to submit this form ?</span>  

<form>
    <input id="yesButton" type="button" value="Yes"/> 
    <input id="noButton" type="button" value="No"/>
</form>

</div>

<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#yesButton').on('click', function() {
            $('#yesButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#noButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            window.location = contextRoot + '/imging/stre/${caseId}/${documentTypeCode}';
        });

        $('#noButton').on('click', function() {
            $('#yesButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#noButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $.ajax({
                url: contextRoot + '/imging/clr/${Id}/${documentTypeCode}',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'text'
            });
            window.close();
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm surprised that's working consistently in ANY browser. access/modify the disabled property with the .prop method, not .attr

Comment: if you put an `alert()` statement in the event handlers does it always show?

Comment: This is from jQuery 1.6, but still applies here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser's console at any point?

Comment: @KevinB No objections that they should be using `.prop()`, but I think jQuery 1.8 would hold their hand and make sure using `.attr()` still disabled the element.

Comment: I get alert sometimes , not alwys and buttons does not grey out when they are clicked

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Agreed, this won't be an issue in 1.7-1.8, only in 1.9. The symptoms do point toward 1.9 though. in 1.9, the first call to it will work, but subsequent calls to it won't have any effect. All speculation of course. @pk2 Where is `contextRoot` defined?

Comment: stop using the language attribute on your script tags. use `type="text/javascript"` or no attribute at all. Also, as mentioned above, do not use `.attr()` for things like `disabled`--use `.prop()` with a boolean value.

Comment: @Kevin B contextRoot is defined in another jsp file , I am using apache tiles  to layout page contents